# Retrieving data under the same child name but different date

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database to retrieve user data into my android studio application. I am looking to sum all of the numbers under the child ("BlueCount") together to get an all time total. I am having trouble retrieving all the "BlueCount" data from each different date.

[image: You can see the firebase database structure here]

I am trying to add all the underlined "BlueCount" values together.

I have tried this but i can only retrieve data from the current date...

```
private TextView blueValue;
private TextView redValue;
private TextView greenValue;
private TextView yellowValue;
private ArrayList<Integer> blist = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> rlist = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> glist = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> ylist = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> bblist = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dataview);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    blueValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blueValue);
    redValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.redValue);
    greenValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.greenValue);
    yellowValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yellowValue);


    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user == null){
        return;
    }

    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    final Date date = new Date();

    String userID = user.getUid();
    String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
    databaseReference.child("users")
    .child(userID)
    .child(strDate)
    .child("BlueCount").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            int num = 0;
            String holder = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            num += Integer.parseInt(holder.trim());
            blist.add(num);

            int sum = 0;
            for (int counter=0;counter<blist.size();counter++){
                sum+= blist.get(counter);
            }
            blueValue.setText(" "+sum);

        }


        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase can only load complete nodes, or nodes that can be queries. So you'll have to load all data, and then loop over each level to determine the totals.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
DatabaseReference userReference = databaseReference.child("users").child(userID);

userReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    long totalBlueCount = 0;
    for (DataSnapshot yearSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      for (DataSnapshot monthSnapshot: yearSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        for (DataSnapshot daySnapshot: monthSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          DataSnapshot blueSnapshot = daySnapshot.child("BlueCount");
          long dayBlueCount = 0;
          for (DataSnapshot daySnapshot: monthSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            long count = Long.parseLong(daySnapshot.getValue(String.class));
            dayBlueCount += count;
          }
          System.out.println(yearSnapshot.getKey()+"-"+monthSnapshot.getKey()+"-"+daySnapshot.getKey()+": blue count = "+dayBlueCount);
          totalBlueCount += dayBlueCount;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Total blue count = "+totalBlueCount);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException();
  }
}
```

I would consider if the hierarchy really helps you here, as the code would be a lot simpler if each day was just at the same level under a user `"2019-07-16"`, `"2019-07-17"`, etc.

Comment: Code looks good other then the line "DataSnapshot blueSnapshot = daySnapshot.getChild("BlueCount");"... Android Studio is not happy with the getChild("BlueCount"). How can i fix this?

Comment: Ah yes, that should've been `child(...)`. I updated my answer. I highly recommend browsing the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) to learn how to fix that type of mistake in an answer.